# how can I search smiler word in a string by using php

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have one array like this `$questions = ['how ara you','what are the products','tell me about yourself']` and one variable like this `$str = 'hello how are you'` .

If this variable is available in that array  then I diplay one result.I tried like below.

```
$match = array_search(strtolower($str), $questions);   //here  that string match exaclty that time only result is comming like
```

`'how ara you'` is the value of $questions array but in string($str) `'hello how are you'`  ,so here hello is not there in array , because of that I am not geeting result .

If string `$str = 'how are you'`  I am geting the results.

how can I do search by words by using php.

Comment: @Jeto Sorry I did not get which parenthesis ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `stripos` to search for a string portion in string.So your common strings are in `questions` array and the searching string is in `str` variable.`stripos` will search for the occurrences of `str` in the every element in the array of `questions` for matching the first occurrence in case-insensitive manner.So you don't need to lower case the searching string.

```
$questions = ['how are you','what are the products','tell me about yourself'];

$str = 'hello how are you';

foreach ($questions as $item) {
    if (( stripos( $item, $str ) !== FALSE ) || ( stripos( $str, $item ) !== FALSE )){
         echo $item;
    }
}
```

you can also use `array_filter` to get the matched items in an array. Just replace the loop with this.

```
$matched = array_filter( $questions, function ( $item ) use ( $str )
{
    if (( stripos( $item, $str ) !== FALSE ) || ( stripos( $str, $item ) !== FALSE )){
        return $item;
   }
});
```

Comment: @AI-Amin Thanks for your response ,but if I give ```about yourself``` in a string that response is not comming ,in your case i should give ```tell me about yourself```,is there nay way to mactch particuler word .

Comment: okay , i have updated the answer to match your string from both sides , check now